# withdrawEth - undeclard indentifer error

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin

can some help: I am getting withdrawEth - Undeclared indentifier error compiling the below contract:

```
contract MyToken is ERC20, Pausable, Ownable {
    event MTKBuyEvent (
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    );
    
    event MTKSellEvent (
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    );

    mapping (address => uint256) pendingWithdrawals;


    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol) ERC20(_name, _symbol) public { 
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000);
    }

    // A wallet sends Eth and receives MTK in return
    function buyToken(uint256 _amount) external payable {
        // Ensures that correct amount of Eth sent for MTK
        // 1 ETH is set equal to 1 MTK
        require(_amount == ((msg.value / 1 ether)), "Incorrect amount of Eth.");
        transferFrom(owner, msg.sender, _amount);
        emit MTKBuyEvent(owner, msg.sender, _amount);
    }
    
    // A wallet sends MTK and receives Eth in return
    function sellToken(uint256 _amount) public {
        pendingWithdrawals[msg.sender] = _amount;
        transfer(owner, _amount);
        **withdrawETH();**
        emit MTKSellEvent(msg.sender, owner, _amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the contracts you inherit from (`ERC20, Pausable, Ownable`) are standard contracts and only have their standard functionality, you simply don't have function `withdrawETH` defined anywhere.

You are either using a wrong name or you forgot to implement the function.

Furthermore your buying and selling logic is incorrect. Buying should send tokens from the contract and should use `transfer`. Selling should take tokens from the seller with `transferFrom` and the transfer needs to be pre-approved.